# how to change date add hours in date angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have below code i want to show date according to hours how to add 48 hours in my current date please help me in this i am new in angularjs.

```
"startjob_datetime" : ISODate("2017-03-13T14:21:12.231Z"),

          var hours  = 48 ;
         var startdate  = new Date(schedule_entry.startjob_datetime);
        var enddate  = new Date(schedule_entry.startjob_datetime).setHours(hours  );
```

i want enddate =  ISODate("2017-03-15T14:21:12.231Z"),
but its not working please check

and if normal working hours is 8 , than  how to change date according to this, because 48 hours means two days, but if 8 hours normal duty time  , it is almost 5 days

Comment: `Date(new Date(schedule_entry.startjob_datetime).setHours(hours));` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
"startjob_datetime" : ISODate("2017-03-13T14:21:12.231Z"),

          var hours  = 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ; //Since 1hr = 60 mins, 1 min = 60 seconds, 1 second= 1000 milliseconds
         var startdate  = new Date(schedule_entry.startjob_datetime);
        var enddate  = new Date(schedule_entry.startjob_datetime).getTime() + hours ;  
 );
```

//This will give you endDate in milliseconds
//And replace 48 with whatever hours you want to add to the start date